# angular 15 when router navigates away from lazy module, last component is still visible

Tags: angular, angular-ui-router

I have an angular 15 app that is displaying a very strange behavior.

I have a lazy loaded module with routes called records.
If I navigate to any route within this "records" module and then try to load any route **outside** that module, the last loaded component from the "records" module remains visible.

Here is my routes definition:

```
export const APP_ROUTES: Routes = [
  { path: 'home', pathMatch: 'full', component: HomeComponent },
  { path: 'login', pathMatch: 'full', redirectTo: '/user/login' },
  {
    path: 'user',
    loadChildren: () =>
    import('@t3/training-tracker-web/feature-user').then(
      (m) => m.FEATURE_USER_ROUTES
      ),
  },
  {
    path: 'records',
    loadChildren: () =>
      import('@t3/training-tracker-web/feature-personal-records').then(
        (m) => m.PersonalRecordsRoutes
      ),
  },
  { path: '', pathMatch: 'full', component: HomeComponent },
  { path: '**', component: PageNotFoundComponent },
];
```

here is the definition of my lazy module routes:

```
export const RecordsRoutes: Route[] = [
  { path: 'add-record', component: RecordsAddComponent },
  { path: 'record-list', component: RecordsListComponent },
  { path: 'record-detail', component: RecordsDetailComponent },
  { path: '', component: FeatureRecordsComponent },
];
```

I use routerlink directives in my components to navigate like this:

```
   <button mat-menu-item [routerLink]="'/records'">All Records</button>
   <button mat-menu-item [routerLink]="'/records/add-record'">Add Record</button>
```

Here is the really weird thing.  I have a toggle in my menu that triggers a change in the dom for light vs dark mode.  It chnages a class on the body element.  If I toggle the theme, the component that should not be visible disappears.
It is like something in the records module prevents a view update after navigating away.

Also, I have another lazy loaded module "users" that does not display this behavior.  My problem is specific to the "records" module.

### EDIT 1

SO I was able to narrow down the issue.  I am using NX libs for my lazy loaded route and I am using stand alone components.  I have a shared UI module in another lib, and any component that imports this shared ui module gives the error I describe above, that is not being unloaded when routing away from that component.

I don't have a solution yet but I am closer to figuring it out.

here is my shared module def:

```
@NgModule({
  imports: [
    CommonModule,
    MaterialModule,
    ReactiveFormsModule,
    RouterLinkWithHref,
    HttpClientModule,
    AngularSvgIconModule.forRoot(),
  ],
  declarations: [PrimaryContentCardComponent, AppShellComponent],
  providers: [provideAnimations()],
  exports: [PrimaryContentCardComponent, MaterialModule, AppShellComponent],
})
export class SharedUiModule {}
```

### EDIT 2

here is my app component in the root angular app that uses the app-shell component:

```
<t3-app-shell
  [darkTheme]="darkTheme$ | async"
  class="app-content-wrapper"
  (signOutEvent)="signOutEvent()"
  (toggleThemeEvent)="toggleThemeEvent(false)"
>
  <router-outlet></router-outlet>
</t3-app-shell>
```

I extracted the app-shell component into its own stand alone component, but the issue remains

Can someone help me figure out why these components are not removed from the dom after navigating away from them

Comment: if component is not displayed, maybe it's matching routing issue? could you [enable routing debug](https://angular.io/api/router/withDebugTracing) and verify? Can you also provide a working stackblitz?

Comment: are there any errors in console? do you use any custom logic that moves elements across dome, without properly notifying angular?

Comment: @akkonrad the component is displayed, the problem is that it does not get removed when navigating away.  I have examined the routing debug logs in the console but cannot see anything wrong

Comment: @Andrei there are no errors in the console and there are no guards, intercepts or other logic that interact with the router.  However,

Comment: I think there could be something in your modules that provides routes in the places where they shouldn't be provided. also a couple of things that look strange in your code: 
AppShellComponent in shared module(If it is used as a root of the application, it shouldn't be available for every component) and RouterLinkWithHref directive(just put Router module in its place).

Comment: @Andrei I removed the app-shell component into its own stand alone component, however, I am still getting the issue.  The code in edit 2 is the only place there is a router-outlet.  My shared ui module now contains mostly material ui and scss files.

Comment: @Andrei once I removed the shared module from all the stand alone components, the router behavior went back to normal.  I am still not sure what it is in the shared module that is causing the problem.  But if you post an answer about removing the app-shell from the shared ui etc I will accept it

Comment: where is APP_ROUTES used? it is probably provided in several places, but should be in one

Comment: @Andrei the APP_ROUTES is used in only one place, the main app module imports it

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem was mixing modules and stand alone components in this app.  I am trying to migrate to stand alone and was starting with the lazy loaded routes/components.

The problem was importing the sharedUI module into all my stand alone components.  I removed the shared UI module import and only imported the specific things needed into each stand alone component.

Once I did this the routing worked normally.